# Android NDK doesn't support std::locale()?

Tags: android, android-ndk, locale, stlport

I use std::local() to MBS to WCS in Android NDK.

But...

```
std::locale::global(std::locale("kor"))
std::locale::global(std::locale("ko"))
std::locale::global(std::locale("ko_KR"))
std::locale::global(std::locale("ko_KR.eucKr"))
std::locale::global(std::locale("ko_KR.euckr"))
std::locale::global(std::locale("ko_KR.EUCKR"))
```

All lead to crashes.

and...
`std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"))` also crashes.

Is `std::locale()` not supported in Android NDK?

My STL library is

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57313) the answer is No.

> There is no support for locales in the C library / from native code, and this is intentional.
>   As Elliot pointed out, your only hope is to use JNI to get relevant values.